# Show that there isn't such element $\tau$ so $\tau^2=(123456)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I'd like to know if my solution is correct:

Assume there exists a permutation $\tau$ so that $\tau^2 = (123456)$

$\tau$ is a permutation, so it can be written as a multiplication of transpositions. The permutation $\tau^2$ will contain $2$ times the transpositions in $\tau$. That leads us to conclude that $\tau^2$ is an even permutation, hence it can't be equal to $(123456)$, which is an odd permutation.

Comment: Right, except that what you call "transportations" are "transpositions".

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $transpositions$ instead of transportations right?

Comment: $(123456)$ is an odd permutation? You never stop learning.

Comment: @ProfessorVector yes since $(123456)=(12)(23)(34)(45)(56)$ is the product of five transpositions, an odd number of transpositions (*following the convention that permutation composition is applied right to left*).

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm sorry, that was just confusion with notation, it's a cycle, not the identical permutation.

Comment: Hrm, I thought it was group theory 101 to show a cycle of even length is odd and cycles of odd length is even.

Comment: E_K : next time you want to post a solution to a question and you don't have any concrete thing to ask about, please post the question as a question and the solution as a solution. It is not good practice to ask questions where the answer is, in all likelihood, "yes, that's right." And, as always, see if your question has been posted already, and if you like, post your solution to *that*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the reasoning is correct.

If you have a homomorphism $\operatorname{sgn}:S^6\to\{\pm 1\}$ (the *sign homomorphism*), you could say that $\operatorname{sgn}(\tau^2)=\operatorname{sgn}(\tau)^2=(\pm 1)^2=1$, so $\tau^2$ is even.

I am not sure your particular reason for why $(123456)$ is odd, maybe you should mention it (I suspect it is because it is a cycle and you are appealing to a theorem).  But it is not too hard to write it as a product of transpositions: $(12)(23)(34)(45)(56)$.

---

A sign-determination trick I particularly like is to draw the permutation graphically, adjust the lines until the intersections only involve two lines at a time, and then count off the number of crossings mod 2.  As a bonus, it gives a decomposition as a product of transpositions.  The following diagrams are read bottom-to-top:

[image: Decomposition of (123456)]

A decomposition of $(123456)$ as $\tau^2$ would involve moving the lines around until there are equal numbers of crossings above and below some horizontal line, but the number of crossings is odd.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the permutation is odd since for every $k$, a k-cycle is an even permutation iff k is odd.

Comment: Could you explain please the right diagram? What is the meaning of the diagonal line?

Comment: I just took the permutation on the left and made the crossings appear more clearly by bending the lines.  For example, the bottom-most slice is the permutation $(1)(2)(3)(4)(56)=(56)$.  When you read it off, you read the slice by itself -- don't worry about the entire line, just how it passes through the slice.  That's why the second slice from the bottom is $(45)$, for instance.

Comment: Oh i get it, i thought it has a meaning as a whole line, but now I see it is composed of 5 parts: 6->5->4->3->2->1. Cool trick!